# Object key based on array values

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have array: `const arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'bax'];`

I want to create an object based on array entries:

```
const obj = {
  foo: true,
  bar: true,
  bax: false,
  fax: true, // typescript should show error here because "fax" is not in "arr"
};
```

How to tell typescript that all keys of `obj` must be inside `arr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
const arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'bax'] as const;

type MappedObject = Record<typeof arr[number], boolean>;

const obj: MappedObject = {
  foo: true,
  bar: true,
  bax: false,
  fax: true, // typescript should show error here because "fax" is not in "arr"
};
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gcgGYhJgGhkwCNFDiyAPTAXXghlEigG4BYAKC6gE8AHAKYwAsnH5CAJgHkSAK0HBYaAEqKQCSQB4+QkNnhJ0YAK4BbEoIS0iJPABtBcMAD4O3Ts2gwQ8gFyi4lKyCkqoMADeXDAwuCABUAgmggTRMGQICUkpadQB2HD2EDmcMQVUWclEAPTVMLqCEMAIAJb8sBAAFiAm9pIwXSAA7jBWCBownVbClsBwJsUwAETlSzAtjGAgsC1gy4gIS1wAvqxAA)

Related GitHub issue - [Microsoft/TypeScript#28046](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28046)

Comment: Related GitHub issue [Microsoft/TypeScript#28046](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28046)

Answer (score -1):

```js
const arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'bax'];

//I want to create an object based on array entries:

const obj = {
  foo: true,
  bar: true,
  bax: false,
  fax: true, // typescript should show error here because "fax" is not in "arr"
};

for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj))
{
  if(!arr.includes(key))
  {
    console.log(`error, ${key}: ${value} not found in array`)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I asked for typescript solution not javsscript

Comment: @underfrankenwood Typescript is a subset of javascript, so technically this is a typescript solution.

Comment: Subset? I think you mean super set. Anyways this is not what I expected. Sorry